# Upload files from another server in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

Does anybody knows how to upload a file from an external server to your application by ASP.NET?

For example you wanna upload an image from www.A.Com/1.jpg into your server. How can I implement that in ASP.NET?

I guess it can possible with a webservice but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a URL to any file, you will be able to download it using C# method: [WebClient.DownloadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and you can call this method from any c# program, website, web service,  ....